# Debugging Wordpress Email functionality

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am taking over a wordpress website that i have moved from wordpress to azure. The site has a button at the bottom that sends out an email when clicked. Here is the html for the onclick method

```
<div class="w-form-json hidden" onclick="return {ajaxurl:http:\/\/loancoreignite.azurewebsites.net\/engine\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php,success:Thank you! Your message was sent.,errors:{name:Please enter your Name,email:Please enter your Email,phone:Please enter your Phone Number}}"></div>
```

When i go to that ajax url, i get a 0 in the upper left corner with a 404 error in debug tools. So i located the admin-ajax.php file and tried figuring it out from there but this is where i get lost. Below is the admin-ajax.php file.

```
    <?php
/**
 * WordPress AJAX Process Execution.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
 */

/**
 * Executing AJAX process.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
}

/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );

/** Allow for cross-domain requests (from the frontend). */
send_origin_headers();

// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );

/** Load WordPress Administration APIs */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

/** Load Ajax Handlers for WordPress Core */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php' );

@header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
@header( 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex' );

send_nosniff_header();
nocache_headers();

/** This action is documented in wp-admin/admin.php */
do_action( 'admin_init' );

$core_actions_get = array(
    'fetch-list', 'ajax-tag-search', 'wp-compression-test', 'imgedit-preview', 'oembed-cache',
    'autocomplete-user', 'dashboard-widgets', 'logged-in',
);

$core_actions_post = array(
    'oembed-cache', 'image-editor', 'delete-comment', 'delete-tag', 'delete-link',
    'delete-meta', 'delete-post', 'trash-post', 'untrash-post', 'delete-page', 'dim-comment',
    'add-link-category', 'add-tag', 'get-tagcloud', 'get-comments', 'replyto-comment',
    'edit-comment', 'add-menu-item', 'add-meta', 'add-user', 'closed-postboxes',
    'hidden-columns', 'update-welcome-panel', 'menu-get-metabox', 'wp-link-ajax',
    'menu-locations-save', 'menu-quick-search', 'meta-box-order', 'get-permalink',
    'sample-permalink', 'inline-save', 'inline-save-tax', 'find_posts', 'widgets-order',
    'save-widget', 'delete-inactive-widgets', 'set-post-thumbnail', 'date_format', 'time_format',
    'wp-remove-post-lock', 'dismiss-wp-pointer', 'upload-attachment', 'get-attachment',
    'query-attachments', 'save-attachment', 'save-attachment-compat', 'send-link-to-editor',
    'send-attachment-to-editor', 'save-attachment-order', 'heartbeat', 'get-revision-diffs',
    'save-user-color-scheme', 'update-widget', 'query-themes', 'parse-embed', 'set-attachment-thumbnail',
    'parse-media-shortcode', 'destroy-sessions', 'install-plugin', 'update-plugin', 'press-this-save-post',
    'press-this-add-category', 'crop-image', 'generate-password', 'save-wporg-username',
);

// Deprecated
$core_actions_post[] = 'wp-fullscreen-save-post';

// Register core Ajax calls.
if ( ! empty( $_GET['action'] ) && in_array( $_GET['action'], $core_actions_get ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_GET['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_GET['action'] ), 1 );

if ( ! empty( $_POST['action'] ) && in_array( $_POST['action'], $core_actions_post ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_POST['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_POST['action'] ), 1 );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 1 );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    /**
     * Fires authenticated AJAX actions for logged-in users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the AJAX action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
    /**
     * Fires non-authenticated AJAX actions for logged-out users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the AJAX action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
// Default status
die( '0' );
```

Maybe this is easier than im making it out to be and all that is needed is something in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not, but I feel obligated to say it:

**Please never edit WP Core files!!**

As for your problem, it could be a number of things. WP Ajax requires an 'action' to be set. Please see this link for more information on setting AJAX "actions": https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Second, when WP AJAX returns `0` that means either the AJAX "action" (as mentioned above) could not be found OR the PHP function does not have `die()` at the end. You **must** add `die();` at the end of the PHP function triggered by the AJAX and you **must** declare the action from the link above.

Create a PHP function to send the email in your functions.php file. Create the action from the link above and set the callback as the PHP function. At the end of the function, put `die();` and then things should start to work as expected.

There are two types of AJAX actions, the `wp_ajax-your-function` and `wp_ajax_nopriv-your-function`. The first of the two will allow your AJAX request to be done from wp-admin, the second (the one with `_nopriv`) will allow your ajax request to be triggered from the frontend.

If you need an example, just ask. I can pull one from an existing site to show you.

Comment: I would love an example. As you say since it returns 0 it could be either the action is not found or the function doesnt have a die at the end. As you can see from the file, the file does have a die at the end. So it must be that the action cannot be found. How can i go about trying to find it based off of the PHP file itself.

Also, would there be a way for me to step through the admin-ajax.php to see where the code is returning a 0 to see potentially where i need to go next?

Answer (score 0):

Need to fix your JSON

```
<div class="w-form-json hidden" onclick="return {ajaxurl:'http:\/\/loancoreignite.azurewebsites.net\/engine\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php',success:'Thank you! Your message was sent.',errors:{name:'Please enter your Name',email:'Please enter your Email',phone:'Please enter your Phone Number'}}"></div>
```

even still I don't see how that was doing anything.